# Form background gradient but not below input

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, background-color

I'm trying to do a form with a background gradient, but I don't want it below the input fields. I'd like to see a white background color in input fields, but I can't use this property because of a label, I have to make it white styling the whole form.
I'm using this code:

```css
.login_form{
position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
width:80%;
height:auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 3px;
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ffd27f, #ffe4b2, #ffd27f);
}
.col-3{width:68%;margin: 20px 16%; position: relative;padding-left:0;padding-right:0;!important}
input[type="text"],input[type="password"]{font: 14px/23px "Lato", Arial, sans-serif; color: #333;background-color:transparent; width: 100%; margin-

left:0%;box-sizing: border-box; letter-spacing: 1px;outline:none;border-radius:4px;}
.effect-16{padding: 6px 10px; border: 1px solid #aaa; border-radius:3px;background-color: transparent;}

.effect-16 ~ .focus-border{position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 0; height: 2px; background-color: #3399FF; transition: 0.4s;}
.effect-16:focus ~ .focus-border,
.has-content.effect-16 ~ .focus-border{width: 100%; transition: 0.4s;}
.effect-16 ~ label{position: absolute; left: 10px; width: 100%; font-size:85%; top: 7px; color: #888; transition: 0.3s; z-index:-1; letter-spacing: 0.5px;}
.effect-16:focus ~ label, .has-content.effect-16 ~ label{top: -20px; font-size: 12px; color: #3385ff; transition: 0.3s;}
.effect-16:focus + .has-content.effect-16 ~ label{top: -20px; font-size: 12px; color: #3385ff; transition: 0.3s;}
.curnot{cursor:not-allowed;}
.btni{pointer-events: none;margin-left:24%;width:52%;margin-bottom: 15px;text-align:center;background-color:#a0cad8;border:2px solid #a0cad8; 

outline:none; color:white;padding-top:7px;padding-bottom:7px;border-radius:3px;font:bold 92% Lato, sans-serif;}
.btni:hover{color:white;}
```

```html
<form method="post" class="login_form" action="email_check.php" autocomplete="off">
<h1 class="title_login">Registrati</h1>
<div class="col-3 input-effect" style="margin-top:40px;">
            <input class="effect-16" type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off">
            <label>Scegli Username</label>
            <span class="focus-border" id="focususername"></span>
        </div>
<div class="col-3 input-effect">
            <input class="effect-16" type="text" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="off">
            <label>Email</label>
            <span class="focus-border" id="focusemail"></span>
        </div>
<div class="col-3 input-effect">
            <input class="effect-16" type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off">
            <label>Password</label>
            <span class="focus-border" id="focpassword"></span>
        </div>
<div class="col-3 input-effect">
            <input class="effect-16" type="password" name="confirm" id="confirm" autocomplete="off">
            <label>Conferma password</label>
            <span class="focus-border" id="focconfirm"></span>
        </div>
<div class="curnot">
<input type="submit" name="login" id="invia" class="btni" value="Avanti">
</div>
</form>
```

Should I use the :not selector? If yes, how?

Sorry for my bad English, I hope it can be understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use these code

```css
    .login_form{
    position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
    width:80%;
    height:auto;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      border-radius: 3px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ffd27f, #ffe4b2, #ffd27f);
    }
    .login_form .col-3{width: 68%;
    margin: 25px 16%;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;}
    input[type="text"],input[type="password"]{
          font: 14px/23px "Lato", Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
    .effect-16{padding: 6px 10px; border: 1px solid #aaa; border-radius:3px;background-color: transparent;}

    .effect-16 ~ .focus-border{position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 0; height: 2px; background-color: #3399FF; transition: 0.4s;}
    .effect-16:focus ~ .focus-border,
    .has-content.effect-16 ~ .focus-border{width: 100%; transition: 0.4s;}
    .effect-16 ~ label{position: absolute; left: 10px; width: 100%; font-size:85%; top: 7px; color: #888; transition: 0.3s;  letter-spacing: 0.5px;}
    .effect-16:focus ~ label, .has-content.effect-16 ~ label{top: -20px; font-size: 12px; color: #3385ff; transition: 0.3s;}
    .effect-16:focus + .has-content.effect-16 ~ label{top: -20px; font-size: 12px; color: #3385ff; transition: 0.3s;}
    .curnot{cursor:not-allowed;}
    .btni{pointer-events: none;margin-left:24%;width:52%;margin-bottom: 15px;text-align:center;background-color:#a0cad8;border:2px solid #a0cad8; 

    outline:none; color:white;padding-top:7px;padding-bottom:7px;border-radius:3px;font:bold 92% Lato, sans-serif;}
    .btni:hover{color:white;}
```

```html
 

    <form method="post" class="login_form" action="email_check.php" autocomplete="off">
    <h1 class="title_login">Registrati</h1>
    <div class="col-3 input-effect" style="margin-top:40px;">
                <input class="effect-16" type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off">
                <label>Scegli Username</label>
                <span class="focus-border" id="focususername"></span>
            </div>
    <div class="col-3 input-effect">
                <input class="effect-16" type="text" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="off">
                <label>Email</label>
                <span class="focus-border" id="focusemail"></span>
            </div>
    <div class="col-3 input-effect">
                <input class="effect-16" type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off">
                <label>Password</label>
                <span class="focus-border" id="focpassword"></span>
            </div>
    <div class="col-3 input-effect">
                <input class="effect-16" type="password" name="confirm" id="confirm" autocomplete="off">
                <label>Conferma password</label>
                <span class="focus-border" id="focconfirm"></span>
            </div>
    <div class="curnot">
    <input type="submit" name="login" id="invia" class="btni" value="Avanti">
    </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give the input field a background color of white and remove the z-index on the label so it sits on top. I noticed the label moves to the top on the focus of the input.

see screenshot below
[Tested the form by giving the input a background-color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzG3E.png)